# How to implement user enrollment or subscription?

Tags: 7, users

I want to create a website with few courses in it. Each course will have a node of content type `Course`. I want users to be able to enter the course.

So this is sort of a "many-to-many" relationship question for Drupal, as for each subscription I will need to keep details on the progress, e.g. "last completed lesson", "total score", etc.

Is there a module that will have Enrollment/Subscription as a separate Entity/Content or [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module will do it?

What is the best approach?

**UPDATE 1**:

- This should allow to show all students subscribed to a course on a course page;
- Show all current subscriptions with their details (fields) to student on my_courses page.

**UPDATE 2**: Can I use Open Group module for that?

Comment: I think http://drupal.org/project/entityreference will do what you're wanting.

Comment: @Cthos can I add fields to subscriptions via entity reference? It looks like Relation might be a more suitable solution...

Comment: Sure, you'd make a content type of "Progress" which would be owned by a user, which is then referenced by the course. You'd use views/blocks to show that information on a course dashboard page, and so on. Though, the Relation page itself says "While a similar module could be built based on Entityreference and Entity Construction Kit (ECK) by creating a custom entity and adding entity reference fields to it [...]" - That implies that both of the modules could do what you're proposing.

Comment: Sounds good, I will test both methods tomorrow. Thanks. I actually did not think of `author` as a reference field.

Comment: One other module that I did not consider yet, is OG. Can it be used for that? I think I will have to use it anyway for other purposes, so if OG Membership is configurable, it might do the trick.

Comment: I can't vouch for that as I've not used it before.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this can be done with [Entity Registration](http://drupal.org/project/registration) module.

Answer (score 0):

You could build it yourself, or why not go for a free ride? The [OpenAcademy distribution](http://drupal.org/project/openacademy) looks like it is preconfigured with the kind of things that you would need.

Comment: I guess I will have a look at OpenAcademy's implementation, but this is sort of theoretical question on finding the optimal way to implement the subscription. Enrollment is just an example.

Comment: I had a look at openacademy's source, and it has all modules one can imagine. I could not figure out which module(s) they used to implement enrollment process.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give it a try to use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, which allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections.

It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable. Every group can have users, roles and permissions attached to it (refer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197493/39516)" for more details about that).

## Sample configuration

Below is an example of a possible configuration, which may help to get you started with possible configurations (using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module):

```
Group type ID ! Group type ! Group role ID ! Role
--------------+------------+---------------+------------
 1            ! Class      ! 3             ! Instructor
 1            ! Class      ! 4             ! Student
 2            ! Customers  ! 5             ! Lead
 2            ! Customers  ! 6             ! Prospect
 2            ! Customers  ! 7             ! Licensed Customer
 2            ! Customers  ! 8             ! Sales
 2            ! Customers  ! 9             ! Support
 2            ! Customers  ! 10            ! Accounting
 2            ! Customers  ! 11            ! R&D
 3            ! Project    ! 12            ! Project Manager
 3            ! Project    ! 13            ! Developer
 3            ! Project    ! 14            ! Customer
```

#### Group Types

The above example consists of 3 ***group types***:

- Class.
- Customers.
- Project.

#### Group Roles

For each of the 3 group types, there are specific ***Roles*** defined, some more details about some of them:

- for the *Class* group, these are the 2 roles that are configured:

  - Instructor.
  - Student.
- for the *Project* group, these are the 3 roles that are configured:

  - Project Manager.
  - Developer.
  - Customer.

These are the *Group Specific Roles*: these roles can be configured per group type and will only be available on groups of that group type. As an example, for group type "*Class*", the defined roles are **Instructor** and **Student** (which are not available for the other group types.

On top of the group specific roles, there are also *Special Global Roles*: These are the special (hardcoded) roles named **Outsider** (= a signed in user that did not join a group) and **Member**  (= a signed in user that did join a group). These cannot be defined by the Drupal administrator, and they are always available for any group. These roles can have different permissions sets for each group type. Special case: the role **Anonymous** is related to a user that is not signed.

#### Groups

Each of the configured group types can have any number of ***Groups***.

Examples of groups:

- for the *Class* group type, there could be these **Groups**:

  - Getting started with Drupal.
  - Drupal for site builders.
  - Become an expert in using the Rules module.
- for the *Customers* group type, there could be these **Groups**:

  - Service Requests.
  - Order Processing.
  - Sales Orders.
  - Relationship Management.

#### Permissions

For each of the configured group types, you can then also configure for each ***Content Type*** which ***Role*** has what kind of access (= none, view, create, edit, delete). Be aware: even though this looks similar to Drupal's permission configuration, these permissions are not the same permissions (they are specific to the Group module).

## Comparison with the Organic groups module

Have a look at my answer to "[What are the features of the Group module versus Organic Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197618/what-are-the-features-of-the-group-module-versus-organic-group-module/197622#197622)" for details about:

- How both modules (Group versus Organic groups) compare to each other.
- Integration with various modules that you might want to take advantage of also.

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

**PS**: this answer applies to either D7 or D8.